# Multiple Users with Same Name

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Whilst reading the thread about Nominations for Moderators, I looked at the [List of Users](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users)

I was surprised that ([as well as me](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/88/andrew)) there is another user [Andrew](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/188/andrew).  I appreciate that the name isn't unique in the big-wide-world but usually forums and similar don't allow the same name?

At the moment, this isn't an issue as he's not active, but I can foresee confusion if the other one started to be active on the site!

Is this expected behaviour on SE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=andrew

Comment: You could use your handle - that's unique!

Comment: Thanks, Jeni - maybe not ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is intentional, user names are not unique on SE sites (the user ids are, though). It isn't a problem usually, even when multiple users have the same name they usually have a different gravatar.

If you want to avoid any possible confusion you can just use a user name that isn't just a first name. You can freely change your name once a month.

Comment: Ta... it just surprised me, as I've not hit a "conflict" on any other SE site that I'm active on.

Comment: just upload a photo! ;)

Comment: I don't actually look like a bunch of green polygons.